# populating char**

Tags: c++

I'm trying to read in a list of files from another file.  The file reading works but populating the array of char* isn't.  It works for the first iteration but then gets a bad pointer on the next line.  I tried with a vector of strings but was having problems, I think due to its destructor trying to free an argv.

```
char **datafiles = (char**)malloc(0);
int filecount = 0;

master.AddDataFiles(argv[1],datafiles,filecount);

int Manager::AddDataFiles(char *filename, char **filelist, int &filecount)
{
    const int LINEMAX = 64;
    struct stat info;
    std::ifstream is(filename);
    if (is.fail()) return 1;

    char buffer[LINEMAX];

    while(!is.eof())
    {
        is.getline(buffer,LINEMAX);
        realloc(filelist,sizeof(char**) * (filecount + 1));
        filelist[filecount] = (char*) malloc(std::strlen(buffer) + 1);
        std::strcpy(filelist[filecount],buffer);
        filecount++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: if you're using `c++`, why not use `std::string`?

Comment: If you're working in C++, then you should really be avoiding raw pointers!  Just use `std::string`.  What sort of problem were you having with them?

Comment: You've managed to get as far as using C++ rather than C (although you originally tagged it as both), so why don't you take the next leap and stop using `char**` and start using `std::string` and some proper containers in which to house them?

Comment: and pointers-to-pointers in particular.

Comment: Might as well use std::vector too.

Comment: the problem with the vector implementation occured elsewhere i think due to the fact that the function that used the string only take char* and not const char*, tried casting copying etc, but somewhere, probaly a stl destructor tried to delete argv for the main

Comment: @user615174 update your question with the problems encountered when using `std::vector<std::string>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `realloc` correctly is a bit tricky -- it can (and sometimes, but not always, will) return a different pointer than the one you passed to it, so you have to do something like this:

```
char **temp = realloc(filelist, sizeof(char**) * filecount+1);
if (temp != NULL)
    filelist = temp;
else
    failed_allocation();
```

Also note that your `while (!file.eof())` is a classic mistake -- it won't sense the end of the file correctly.

I'd revisit the vector of strings option though. Perhaps you could post the code you had, and ask about whatever problem(s) you encountered with it. Getting it to work well will almost certainly be less work than fixing this, and the result will almost certainly be more solid and understandable.

Correct code for this would look something like:

```
std::vector<std::string> Manager::AddDataFiles(std::string const &filename) { 
   std::ifstream infile(filename.cstr());
   std::vector<std::string> filenames;
   std::string temp;
   while (std::getline(infile, temp))
       filenames.push_back(temp);
   return filenames;
}
```

Comment: And the second problem is that the reallocated filelist is not passed back out of the method: the global datafiles remains unchanged.

Comment: of course in C++0x, `filenames.emplace_back(std::move(temp))`

Comment: @Lars: I think that's (at least) the third problem, but it's probably pointless to quibble over the count. :-)

Comment: change to vectors, think the problems i had were related to other realloc in the code

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use `std::vector<std::string>` instead of `char**`? This elegantly solves your problem!

If the filenames do not contain space then here is even more elegant solution (or else you can see Jerry's solution):

```
void Manager::AddDataFiles(const char *filename, std::vector<std::string> &filelist)
{
    std::istream_iterator<string> start(std::ifstream(filename));
    std::istream_iterator<string> end;
    std::copy(start, end, std::back_inserter(filelist));
}
```

For this, you've to include these:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
```

Comment: As Jerry said, `while (!is.eof())` is broken.

Comment: @Ben: Yes. I was thinking so!

Comment: Using a fixed-size buffer is semi-broken as well (a long filename could get broken into pieces and show up as two or more separate strings, none of which was a correct path to a file).

Comment: @Jerry: that depends. Maybe that is the maximum length of filename is allowed in his case. But that is good point.

Comment: @user615174: I replaced my solution with even more elegant solution, as others already have given the solution I removed. So there is no loss in options. You can choose whatever suits your need.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `std::string` and `std::vector<std::string>`. It might also makes sense to have the file list a member.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

void Manager::AddDataFiles(const std::string& filename)
{
    std::ifstream in(filename.c_str());
    for( std::string line; std::getline(in, line); ) {
        filelist.push_back(line);
    }
}
```